# Post request works in postman but not in javascript fetch function

Tags: javascript, php, rest, ecmascript-6, cors

I thought I had solved this issue before and was able to make succesful post request to my local hosted apache server with fetch, but today I tried to make a post and I've gotten 'cors preflight request fail' error again. I'm not sure why it was working before and why it's suddenly not working again.

this is my php file headers which worked 3 days ago -

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, 
  Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

and this is the fetch request I'm using on it  -

```
fetch("http://menu.com/menu/api/post/create.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({
    'title' : 'qweqweqw',
    'body' : '1111w',
    'author' : '2222r',
    'category_id' : '2'
  })
})
.then( (response) => { 
   console.log(response);
});
```

here is the Postman code that is working :

```
POST /menu/api/post/create.php HTTP/1.1
Host: menu.com
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 83a8e0d1-f45a-4184-92f6-f0be2f8fcf5f
{
    "title" : "new new title",
    "body" : "new neqwsadasssssssssseqweqwew jew",
    "author" : "new newzxxxxxxxxxxxxwq author",
    "category_id" : "1"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

edit-

These are the cors errors :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://menu.com/menu/api/post/create.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

In my apache server error log I get this `' PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'category_id' at row 1 in /home/orphe$'` But I'm not sure why it's getting this for category_id since I copy/pasted the working request from postman and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the CORS error you see in the browser console

Comment: the target url is not live

Comment: The response you’re getting is from the CORS preflight OPTIONS request that the browser does automatically on its own. The browser never gets around to even trying your POST request, because that OPTIONS request fails. So to reproduce the error with Postman, you need to send an OPTIONS request, not a POST request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker It still works with an OPTIONS request in postman, only getting a 200 OK response from that.

Comment: add header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, FETCH');, allow the fetch on access allow control. Last time I done that and it works.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a preflight request (with OPTIONS), but the server doesn't return HTTP 200 OK.
Try adding the following to `create.php`:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

If this doesn't work please also include the request and response headers.

Comment: This isn't working I get the same error. I don't really care if it's a post request or options I just want to send the data in. I'm sending it in with postman and it works fine, but for some reason my fetch request keeps failing when I send in the exact same object as in postman..

Answer (score -1):

Changing my fetch requests headers to  `headers: new Headers()` fixed everything.